# metrics.f1_score - length of unsized object

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Newbie to Python and sklearn here. I'm getting a "type error" on the following code that I don't understand. Can anyone help?

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data)
Y = vectorizer.transform(dev_data)

print Y.shape
print dev_labels.shape

parameters = {'n_neighbors':[1,300] }
grid_search = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(), parameters, scoring=metrics.f1_score(Y, dev_labels))
grid_search.fit(X, train_labels)
print "the score is", grid_search.score(Y, dev_labels)
print "The best value is achieved when k = ", grid_search.best_params_
```

train_data, dev_data are basic data used for training the model.  Y.shape is (676, 26879) while dev_labels.shape is (676,)

The error message is "Type_error" on the GridSearchCV line. It says: TypeError: len() of unsized object

What object is unsized?

Comment: I think you should simply give `scoring='f1'`. That should work. You are also  using the `f1_score` method incorrectly. Your first parameter to it is the training data. Instead you are passing it the transformed feature vector which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks; the scoring='f1' fix worked.

Comment: I'll make this as an answer.  You can mark it as accepted answer so that it helps the community.

Comment: Probably you want to search number of neighbors in range(1, 300) but not in [1, 300].

Answer (score 0):

You should simply change `scoring` parameter to `scoring='f1'`. This will do the job for you.

Also you are using the `f1_score` method incorrectly. Your first parameter to it is the training data. Instead you are passing it the transformed feature vector which is not correct.